# Downloading Worldclim data using R

Tags: download

please I need your help. I am trying to donwload worldclim bioclimatic variables using R (the Geodata packages) for a specific spatial extent. Unfortunately, my output folders remain empty. Your help is welcome, thank you! Here is the code I am using:

```
sudan<- readOGR(dsn = ".", layer = "grid_rect4")
WorldClim.CMIP_6.download(
  save.location = "./",
  parameter = "bio",
  bio.var = c(1:5),
  resolution = "2.5m",
  model.var = c("ACCESS-CM2", "BCC-CSM2-MR"),
  emission.scenario.var = c("ssp126", "ssp245", "ssp370", "ssp585"),
  time.interval.var = c("2021-2040", "2041-2060", "2061-2080", "2081-2100"),
  clipping = TRUE,
  clip.shapefile = "sudan",
  clip.extent = c(20, 40, 3, 23),
  buffer = 0,
  convert.files.to.asc = TRUE,
  stacking.data = FALSE,
  keep.raw.zip = TRUE,
  delete.raw.data = FALSE,
  save.bib.file = FALSE``
)
```

I tried to download worldclim data, but my folders ar empty